# JSON request returns 'undefined' for all key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a PHP file that parses a Google Spreadsheet as JSON:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Set your CSV feed
$feed = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IwFDZp1dLBR931OnJpEgW9ojrLx063m5_dhkqKGgugc/pub?output=csv';

// Arrays we'll use later
$keys = array();
$newArray = array();

// Function to convert CSV into associative array
function csvToArray($file, $delimiter) { 
  if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) !== FALSE) { 
    $i = 0; 
    while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 4000, $delimiter, '"')) !== FALSE) { 
      for ($j = 0; $j < count($lineArray); $j++) { 
        $arr[$i][$j] = $lineArray[$j]; 
      } 
      $i++; 
    } 
    fclose($handle); 
  } 
  return $arr; 
} 

// Do it
$data = csvToArray($feed, ',');

// Set number of elements (minus 1 because we shift off the first row)
$count = count($data) - 1;

//Use first row for names  
$labels = array_shift($data);  

foreach ($labels as $label) {
  $keys[] = $label;
}

// Add Ids, just in case we want them later
$keys[] = 'id';

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $data[$i][] = $i;
}

// Bring it all together
for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
  $d = array_combine($keys, $data[$j]);
  $newArray[$j] = $d;
}

// Print it out as JSON
echo json_encode($newArray);

?>
```

And in my HTML, some code that's supposed to render that JSON into an HTML table:

```
<body>
    <div id="id01"></div>

    <script>
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "votos.json.php";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        function myFunction(response) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(response);
            var i;
            var out = "<table>";

            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                out += "<tr><td>" +
                arr[i].Name +
                "</td><td>" +
                arr[i].City +
                "</td><td>" +
                arr[i].Country +
                "</td></tr>";
            }
            out += "</table>";
            document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Accesing index.html shows a table populated by 'undefined' in every cell. However, changing the URL from 'votos.json.php' to some other, like say, for instance, this one pulled from W3: [http://www.w3schools.com/website/customers_mysql.php], the table is populated by the correct data and shows up nicely.
I've validated the JSON output of the PHP file and it doesn't seem to have any problems - so what could be causing this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: most of your csv2array function is pointless. it should just as well be `while($row = fgetcsv(...)) { $arr[] = $row; }`. And have you done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($newArray)` or `console.log(response, arr)` to see what you built and how it arrived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing the incorrect column names from that CSV file. Try...

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    out += "<tr><td>" +
    arr[i].candidato +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].votos +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].porcentaje +
    "</td></tr>";
}
```